# Is the rank $A+\sqrt{2} B$ greater than the rank of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, matrix-rank

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices of same dimensions with rational coefficients.

1. Is $\text{rank } A+\sqrt{2} B \ge \text{rank } A$ and $\text{rank } A+\sqrt{2} B \ge \text{rank } B$?
2. More generally, is it true for any field extension $\mathbf{Q}[x]$?
3. Can we generalize, is $\text{rank } A_0+\sqrt{2} A_1 + \sqrt{3} A_2 + \sqrt{6} A_3  \ge \max\text{rank } A_i$?

Comment: One interesting point is that rank is invariant under field automorphisms. So, $A + \sqrt{2} B$ and $A - \sqrt{2}B$ will necessarily have the same rank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no, even for the weakest of these statements. As a counterexample, consider the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\2&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.
$$
We have $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(B) = 2$, but $\operatorname{rank}(A + \sqrt{2}B) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now.

Comment: A nice example.

Answer (score 2):

Reducing to invertible minors, the question becomes: if $A$ is invertible ( and $A$, $B$ have rational entries), is $A + \alpha B$ invertible for certain $\alpha$'s?  Right away we can multiply by $A^{-1}$ and the question becomes:

Is $I + \alpha C$ invertible

for $C \in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$?  Now we see what the problem is: $C$ might have an eigenvalue $-\frac{1}{\alpha}$.  Of course, that does Not happen if $\alpha$ is $transcendent$. But $\alpha$ algebraic can be a problem.

Comment: Good job explaining how to find counterexamples! It follows that every algebraic number in place of $\sqrt2$ is a problem :-)

Comment: And more specifically, for a fixed size $n$ and $n \times n$ matrices $A,B$, an algebraic number $\alpha$ "is a problem" if its degree is $n$ or smaller.